# Up to three divs inline, left allways present with text variable width not overflow, right two fixed width

Tags: html, css

Parent container is fixed width. Leftmost div is allways present with text of variable length which should be in single line. There are none, one or two divs with fixed width immediately after left div and should move to the right with increasing text length until entire parent is filled. Increasing text lenght further - overflown text should not be visible. Thank you.

```
<td style="width: 300px;">
    <div style="overflow: hidden;float:left;">
       <span>some variable text</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50px;float:left;">fixed1</div>                                                                                                                                                                    
    <div style="width:50px;float:left;">fixed2</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Does this have to be in a table?

Comment: Yes td container is mandatory, but anything within it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT based on comment.**

jQuery solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable td').each(function() {
    var $fixed1 = $(this).children().hasClass('fixed1');
    var $fixed2 = $(this).children().hasClass('fixed2');
    if ($fixed1 && $fixed2) {
      $(this).children('.vText').css('width', '196px');
    }
    if (($fixed1 && !$fixed2) || (!$fixed1 && $fixed2)) {
      $(this).children('.vText').css('width', '248px');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:300px;border:1px solid green;">
      <div style="white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:clip;overflow:hidden;float:left;border:1px solid red;width: 300px;" class="vText">
        <span>some variable text no overflowing</span>
      </div>
      <div style="width:50px;float:left;border:1px solid red;" class="fixed1">fixed1</div>
      <div style="width:50px;float:left;border:1px solid red;" class="fixed2">fixed2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:300px;border:1px solid green;">
      <div style="white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:clip;overflow:hidden;float:left;border:1px solid red;width: 300px;" class="vText">
        <span>some variable text</span>
      </div>
      <div style="width:50px;float:left;border:1px solid red;" class="fixed1">fixed1</div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:300px;border:1px solid green;">
      <div style="white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:clip;overflow:hidden;float:left;border:1px solid red;width: 300px;">
        <span>some variable text</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If there's no fixed div (one of them or both) I'd like to variable text fill their space ie. not leaving empty space as in your example.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that would involve some js/jquery, would that be an option?

Comment: As a last resort.

Comment: Marek, I edited based on your comment. The other answer has the same behavior as my previous one but with flexbox, yet you stated to be what you needed?! If any of the answers help you please consider either upvoting and/or marking correct, thanks.

Comment: Flexbox is doing it right, With text being overflowed if I remove one or both of the fixed width divs, text takes their place, unless your first solution leaved them empty with text being max-width limited.

Comment: Whatever works best for you my friend, I thought when variable text was shorter you still wanted the fixed blocks to the very right of the parent. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed {
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat sit perspiciatis deleniti provident veniam molestias voluptatum itaque odit enim commodi?</div>
  <div class="fixed">50px</div>
  <div class="fixed">50px</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor </div>
  <div class="fixed">50px</div>
  <div class="fixed">50px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this seem to be what I need.